# AWS Ec2- need to create VPC and Subnets before Ec2 instance?

Tags: docker, http, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, subnet

I am trying to create a basic `ec2` instance on which I will run a `docker` container that runs a spring boot web app.

When I go to create the instance I see the below screen.

Do I need to create a `VPC` and `subnets` first before I can create an `Ec2` instance? And is this a new feature of `AWS`?

I want my instance and docker container to be accessible via `http` and `https` on the public internet as spring boot exposes a rest api.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't already have one, you can create your own VPC or use the default one then create a public subnet (with auto-assigned public addresses) in this VPC.

I would recommend to directly create your own VPC.

Since you want your instance being reachable on http and https you want to create a security group that allows connections on ports 80 & 443 and allows connection on port 22 from **your personal IP address only**.

The port 22 will allow you to connect via SSH in the instance to set up your docker container.

Hope it helped!